# JodaTime: get date(s) between two dates using specific interval

Tags: java, jodatime

With JodaTime I am currently checking the amount of days between start date and end date like this:

```
todayDate = new DateTime();
expiryDate = new DateTime(dbReportModel.getValidityTime());
lastDate = new DateTime(dbReportModel.getLastDate());

Days dayDifference = Days.daysBetween(new LocalDate(todayDate), new LocalDate(expiryDate));
```

I start to notify my users about something if the above day difference is less or equal that some `int` of days:

```
if (dayDifference.getDays() <= expiryNotificationProperties.getDaysBefore())
```

The program is ran every day. The problem is that I do not need to send out information every day. I only need to notify every f.e. 15 days.

Currently I have this method to get a list of dates that are in between the given start and end date using the interval:

```
private List<LocalDate> getDatesBetweenExpiryDateTodayDate (DateTime todayDate, DateTime expiryDate, int interval) {
        List<LocalDate> listOfDatesWithInterval = new ArrayList <>();
        int numberOfDays = Days.daysBetween(new LocalDate(todayDate), new LocalDate(expiryDate)).getDays();
        LocalDate dynamicExpiryDate = expiryDate.toLocalDate();
        while (numberOfDays > 0) {
            listOfDatesWithInterval.add(dynamicExpiryDate.minusDays(interval));
            dynamicExpiryDate = dynamicExpiryDate.minusDays(interval);
            numberOfDays -= interval;
        }

        return listOfDatesWithInterval;
    }
```

And this is the additional check that today's date is in the list:

```
List<LocalDate> listOfDatesUsingInterval = getDatesBetweenExpiryDateTodayDate(todayDate, expiryDate, interval);
if (listOfDatesUsingInterval.contains(todayDate.toLocalDate())) {
```

Is it possible to do this in JodaTime in perhaps a better manner? Is there built in functionality to achieve this result?

Comment: Why doesn't it work?

Comment: @lexicore It works. I have edited the post. Is there a better way of implementing such functionality?

Comment: I don't think there is a much better way. The API does not provide such functionality OOTB and you'll land on "startDate + dayIndex" approach one way or another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you could not use Java8 try to use Google Guava:

```
    private static void getDays(DateTime todayDate, DateTime expiryDate, int interval) {
           int numberOfDays = Days.daysBetween(new LocalDate(todayDate), new LocalDate(expiryDate)).getDays();
           Range<Integer> open = Range.closed(1, numberOfDays/interval);
           ImmutableList<Integer> integers = ContiguousSet.create(open, DiscreteDomain.integers()).asList();
           FluentIterable.from(integers).transform(new ConvertToDate(interval)).toList().forEach(System.out::println);
}

private static class ConvertToDate implements Function<Integer, DateTime> {
    private final int interval;

    public ConvertToDate(int interval) {
        this.interval = interval;
    }

    @Override
    public DateTime apply(Integer integer) {
        return DateTime.now().plusDays(integer* interval);
    }
}
```

I don't know if it is better solution but I find it is easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

You can use streams

```
    int numberOfDays = Days.daysBetween(LocalDate.now(), LocalDate.now().plusDays(10)).getDays();
    List<LocalDate> collect = Stream.iterate(LocalDate.now(), e -> e.plusDays(1)).limit(numberOfDays).collect(Collectors.toList());
    collect.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Looks to be doing the job, although I cannot use Java 8 in this project.